# db2 drop few database as once

Tags: shell, unix, db2

recently I started to work with db2, and created few databases.
To drop a single DB I should use `db2 drop db demoDB`, is there a way to drop all DBs at once?

Thanks

Comment: No - does it seem to be too much work? :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first , i don't think there is any db2 nature way to do that. But I usually do the following thing. At start, the way to see all the databases on your instance is one of the following:

1. db2 list db directory
2. db2 list active active databases

Depends on your need ( all DBs or just the active DBs)
I'm sure there is more DBs lists you can get.(at DB2 user guide)

The way I usually drop all my DBs is by using shell script: 
1. create new script by using 'vi db2_drop_all.sh' or some other way you want. 
2. paste the code:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

for db_name in $(db2 list db directory | grep Database | \
                grep name  | cut -d= -f2); do
        db2 drop db $db_name || true
done
exit 0
```

3. save changes
4. and just run the script (after you switched to your instance of course ) `sh db2_drop_all.sh`
Notice that in step 2 you can change the list of DBs as you wish. ( for example to `db2 list active databases`)

Hope it helped you. :)

Comment: Keep in mind that `list db directory` will list local and remote databases, so this script may produce errors if you have any remote databases cataloged on your system.  Ideally your script will only find databases that have `Directory entry type                 = Indirect`

Comment: Also, `list active databases` doesn't necessarily show any databases, if they happen to be inactive.

Comment: You all right. :) I just gave him the a clue how to do that with simple bash script. This script helped me couple of time before.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account the previous answer, this set of lines do the same without creating a script.

```
db2 list db directory | tail -n +6 | sed 'N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;s/\n/ /g' | awk '$28 = /Indirect/ {print "db2 drop database "$7}' | source /dev/stdin
```

This filters the local databases, and executes the generated output.

(Only works in English environment)

Comment: Great suggestion. :)